# How to replace the anchor tag text using C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace the anchor tag value using regex

`Regex.Match(link, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>").Groups[1].Value.ToString();` which gives me the anchor tag text.

I tried to use "Regex. replace" but I am unable to replace the exact text.

Example:

```
var link="<a href="">Sample text </a>";
           var requiredText="new Text";         
           Regex.Replace(link,"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>",requiredText);
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are capturing what is in between in a group.

What you might do instead is capturing what is on the left and on the right in a group and use those 2 capturing groups `$1` and `$2` in the replacement:

```
var link=@"<a href="">Sample text </a>";
var requiredText="$1new Text$2";
link = Regex.Replace(link,"(<a [^>]*>).*?(</a>)",requiredText);
Console.WriteLine(link);
// <a href=">new Text</a>
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/UjGwQ6)

The regex will match:

- `(<a [^>]*>)` Capturing group 1
- `.*?` Match any char 0+ times
- `(</a>)` Capturing group 2

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the anchor tag are purely text (no other tags), you could achieve this using a positive lookbehind and lookahead. By not consuming the anchor opening and closing tags, only the contents will be replaced.

```
/(?<=>)[^<]*(?=<\/a>)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/np0cWp/1)

```cs
string anchor = "<a href=\"\">Sample text </a>";
string requiredText = "new Text";
anchor = Regex.Replace(anchor, @"(?<=>)[^<]*(?=<\/a>)", requiredText);
Console.WriteLine(anchor); // <a href="">new Text</a>
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=>)` - Matches a preceding close angle bracket (lookbehind).
- `[^<]*` - Matches and consumes zero or more characters that aren't an open angle bracket.
- `(?=<\/a>)` - Matches a succeeding close anchor tag (lookahead).

NB: We don't need to know which tag was opened in the lookbehind, because the closing anchor tag must be closing the last opened tag.